# Doctrine2 + CodeIgniter 2 database mapping

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I have a MySQL database with a massive schema already in place and used a plugin for MySQL Workbench to export the structure to a .yml file for Doctrine2

Example of exported YML file:

```
 twitter:
      columns:
        TwitterId:
          type: integer(4)
          primary: true
          notnull: true
        UserId:
          type: integer(4)
          notnull: true
      relations:
        User:
          class: user
          local: UserId
          foreign: UserId
          foreignAlias: twitters
      indexes:
        FK_Twitter_User:
          fields: [UserId]
```

I am using the Doctrine2 CLI and wondering how I can use Doctrine2 to map and auto generate models and entities, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out! I ran

```
php doctrine-cli.php orm:convert-mapping --from-database yml /(your destination folder)/
```

It auto generated entity classes based on my already in place DB schema